# My Site: Enable users to post their biography

Tags: my-site, my-profile, personalization

I am looking for a way to let my users have an editable area on their personnal site where they can enter their bios. The way I thought about doing it is creating a new page with a web part zone using SharePoint Designer and then using the Content Editor web part; however, when I go to add the web part to my created page, Content Editor is nowhere to be found.

Any input on this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

A bio would typically be the About Me section of the user profile. It shows up on the public person.aspx page for the user. That not fitting the bill?

Comment: Unfortunately no. My company wants our users to be able to post their CVs' with a WYSIWYG editor on their profile page.

Comment: That's what the `About me` or any custom HTML property allows

Comment: Upload CV documents to their public folders on their my site? Everyone is going to have it in some document format anyway. Folks with CVs are always in the job market distributing it.